# How to modify/inject custom js in html before page load without extension

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

Is it possible to inject/modify a java script before a html page is loaded without a browser extension?

Im trying to get the value of a function scope variable during loading of the page
because this variable gets unset after the canvas is rendered(im trying to get the value of a canvas chart)

Comment: have you tried the onload property?

Comment: How could I use the onload property to inject code if the page has already been loaded ?

Comment: when are you calling the function to get its variable? During load ? There is also document ready function in JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded using a php script hosted on a local server,

```
<?php

// Set your return content type

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  

$url = $_GET['url'];

//Get that website's content
$handle = fopen($url, "r");

// If there is something, read and return
if($handle)
{
    while(!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 10000000);
        echo $buffer;
    }

    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```